# Will electric field make organic matters (e.g. glucose) ionize in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, water, electricity

After reviewing this [post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22238/why-do-some-substances-ionize-instead-of-dissolving-in-water/68700#68700), I have a new question regarding ionization and dissolution.

If applying a strong electric field (DC or AC) in a water solution, will the electric field ionize the organic matters that are not ionizable? For example, an electric field makes $\ce{CH3COOH}$ ionize more? Or makes glucose ionized in water instead of forming hydrogen bonding with the water molecular? Thanks.

Comment: Stems from a question originally posted by OP in a comment on [this answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/22243/11367).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, particularly for your example of glucose. Part of the key to your question is the statement: "[...] will the electric field ionize the organic matters that are not ionizable?".  If they are not ionizable, then they are not ionizable :)

You could electrolyze glucose to polyhydric alcohols as in [this](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US2303210.pdf) patent. But in this case you are not ionizing glucose, but creating an entirely different compound (which is still not strongly ionic).

There are compounds that can be electrolyzed to ionic compounds, but that is really a very different process than what you are asking about.  You wouldn't have ionization of the compound, you would be electrochemically converting a non-ionic compound into an ionic compound. See for example, [this abstract](http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/92/1/335.abstract)<sup>1</sup> in which the authors electrolyze ethanol to acetic acid, which would then ionize in the aqueous solution to some degree.

But, as in your example of gucose, the ethanol itself would not be ionized. You would simply be producing, via electrochemical reaction, an entirely different, ionic compound.

1) *Journal of the Electrochemical Society, "Electrolytic Oxidation of Ethyl Alcohol to Acetic Acid", 1947, volume 92, issue 1, 335-342*

Comment: Thanks. How about compounds that partially ionizes in water, such CH3COOH? Will an electrical field alter the dynamic equilibrium into another balance?

Comment: No, it's an interesting idea, but an electrical field will not change the degree of ionization of a partially ionized compound. Though the ions may be locally attracted to one pole or the other, that has no effect on the degree of ionization (the dynamic equilibrium between the charged and uncharged species). I hope that helps.

Comment: Even under an extremely strong electromagnetic pulse? Just like tesla coil that can ionize air, can a strong pulse ionize compound in liquid phase?

Comment: Dissolved ions in aqueous solution can carry current, just like the ions formed in  air when the potential of a tesla coil or a spark plug becomes great enough to ionize the air and allow a current to flow. You could certainly blast an aqueous solution with a potential high enough to ionize the water and most anything else in there. But when we're talking about the dissociation of a weak acid for example, the net effect is not going to be an increase of dissociation. Let me continue in the next comment...

Comment: What we're really talking about is the ability of water to solvate the ionic species in solution, and that is not affected by the presence of a magnetic field. In my example of blasting the solution with a high potential, that will just lead to a bunch of new chemical species from the electrolysis reactions. You might even destroy some of your organic acid, forming some other species altogether, but through it all, not counting transient temperature changes and such, the net degree of dissociation of the organic acid will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks. So as I understand, the EM field won't change the ionization or dissociation balance, but only create new chemicals that may ionize by electrolysis. So in the example of Tesla Coil, the air (e.g. oxygen) becomes O2- that is considered as a new chemical. Am I correct? Will the EM field speed up the rate of dissociation/dissolution? For example, it takes 10 mins to get saturated in water under standard condition, then it takes only 30 seconds?

Comment: Yes to everything, almost ;). The EM field would only speed up the rate of dissociation/dissolution due to heating of the solution, and most ionic compounds are more soluble at higher temperatures. There are exceptions though. Calcium hydroxide, for example, is soluble to 1.89 g/L at 0C, but only 0.66 g/L at 100C. In this case, any heating from an EM field-induced reactions to form new compounds would result in lower solubility and slower dissolution of a compound like calcium hydroxide. That's an odd one though, and it sounds to me like you've basically got this figured out; nice job.

Comment: EM field heats the solution is due to speeding up the molecular inner energy. Is that possible the EM field only effect the electron of a certain compound to make the electron more easily to become a free electron, without heating the entire solution?

Comment: Again, to summarize, if there is an electric potential like a Tesla coil within your solution, the potential may ionize anything in the solution where the potential is great enough to do so. The resulting current will heat the solution. The solubility of the solutes, and the dissociation constant of any ions, will have some dependence, positive or negative, on the temperature of the solution. You will _not_ see any difference in the degree of dissociation of a particular ionic compound (i.e. CH3COOH) at any given temperature due to the magnetic field.

Comment: What physical unit (volt or v/m?) should I look at to determine if the EM potential is great enough to ionize compounds in the solution? Should it be correlated to the chemical bond that would be ionized?